# Правильная настройка конфигурации yii2, для работы с БД

Tags: php, yii, yii2

В документации  по Yii2  рассказывают что при работе с формами нужно унаследоваться от класса **Model**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class EntryForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

тут настроены правила валидации и.т.д

**Вопрос**, если эти данные валидные, как будет правильно их записать в БД?  **Нужно ли мне менять  унаследование с model на ActiveRecord?** Или я что то путаю? Конфиг для работы с БД уже настроен.
Только без Gii пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имх в данном случае немного запутывает сам фреймворк, т.к. его валидация является неотъемлемой частью модели (руками же не будешь создавать и заполнять там десяток валидаторов на вводе). В итоге в случаях, как с формой логина - выходит, что надо иметь какую-то модель, чтобы удобно принять ввод и провалидировать его. Но очевидно, что форма логина не является сущностью приложения и ей через орм не соответствует никакая таблица в бд. Т.е. эта модель нужна только для валидации одной конкретной формы. Поэтому предлагают наследоваться от Model и валидировать ввод таким образом, по сути класс Model больше ничего из функционала и не предоставляет.

Если же после работы такой модели-валидатора нужно что-то куда-то записать, то это уже сетится нужной модели ActiveRecord и сохраняется через ее методы. Т.е. в случае формы логина обновить ручками нужное поле у User и сохранить через User::save().

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо, спасибо. Если можно, пожалуйста, покажите минимальный пример. Если у меня модель наследуется от  `Model` и мне нужно записать данные в БД, то как это можно сделать? Вторую модель создавать и там уже наследоваться от ActiveRecord ?

Comment: Покажите вот это пожалуйста -  то это уже сетится нужной модели ActiveRecord и сохраняется через ее методы.

Comment: ну у вас же наверняка есть в приложении модель User, например при логине нужно его last_logon обновить. делать из-за этого EntryForm моделью актив-рекорд - это же неправильно. нужно просто как обычно найти нужного юзера через орм User::find(и т.п.), проставить ему $user->last_logon = 1234, и дернуть $user->save()

Comment: делать или нет две модели - решайте по логике их работы, вполне может быть, что вам нужна просто одна модель ActiveRecord, в ней все валидировать и ей же все сохранять

Comment: вообще в данном случае замените слово Model на слово Validator, оно может так понятнее станет. реальные модели у вас - это ActiveRecord, является ли конкретная форма ввода частью CRUD модели ActiveRecord, или эта форма просто что-то делает сама по себе и требует валидации